# SQL Select where id is in `column`

Tags: sql, csv

I have a column that has multiple numbers separated by a comma. Example for a row:

```
`numbers`:
 1,2,6,66,4,9
```

I want to make a query that will select the row only if the number `6` (for example) is in the column `numbers`.

I cant use `LIKE` because if there is `66` it'll work too.

Comment: Which RDMBS are you using?

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values to begin with

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know. That's an old question that I edited for fixing grammar. Most likely I needed to normalize the data structure...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `like`.  Concatenate the field separators at the beginning and end of the list and then use `like`.  Here is the SQL Server sytnax:

```
where ','+numbers+',' like '%,'+'6'+',%'
```

SQL Server uses `+` for string concatenation.  Other databases use `||` or the `concat()` function.

Comment: Adding the commas to the original string is both effective and concise. I dig it.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your database to rather have a new table that joins numbers with the row of your current table. So if your row looks like this:

```
id   numbers
 1   1,2,6,66,4,9
```

You would have a new table that joins those values like so

```
row_id   number
1        1
1        2
1        6
1        66
1        4
1        9
```

Then you can search for the number 6 in the number column and get the row_id